# js countdown clock reloads every time browser is refreshed, how can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript

The following code produces a countdown clock for 15 days and counts down day, hour, minute, second. But, every time the browser is reloaded the clock restarts? What do I need to to do to change this?

```
<script>function
    getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);</script>
```

Comment: You can either retrive the countdown from server side or use local/session Storage.

Comment: Another option would be to const the end time stamp that you want this timer to end. Then get the current time stamp and subtract one from the other. The rest is the time your timer needs to run. Then break this rest time down to days / hours / mins / secs

Answer (score 0):

`var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);` this is not a static/const value. it's changing every time page load. so you have to find a way to have a static endTime value. as @de-bugged said you can get that either server-side or store in local storage or `use const variable`

like : `const endTime = "Thu Jul 26 2018 11:11:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";`
or like : `const endTime = 1532583817343 //timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do it. Do not use this code though. Its not meant for production :)

I used localstorage here but you can also use session storage, cookies, server side solutions, and const

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <span class="days"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
<script>function
getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


var deadLineTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('deadLineTime')) || false;
if(!deadLineTime){
  deadLineTime = Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  localStorage.setItem('deadLineTime', deadLineTime);
}


var deadline = new Date(deadLineTime2);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```